# How to make text that appears onclick visible for SEO?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, onclick

I have a set of thumbnails and whenever a user clicks a thumbnail I'd like to show a corresponding descriptive text.

I was planning to do it with one div that its innerhtml will change according to the onclicked thumbnail (with javascript). Will all the descriptive text be invisible to robots (seo-wise)?

Any better idea how to implement it?

Comment: Put the text into the alt tag. That's what it's for.

Comment: @Hamish - yes, but it is a very long text (few sentences which describes a video content), from what I've seen people write in the alt tag only several words, isn't it?

Comment: The `alt` tag text can be as long as you want.

Comment: You can use the `title` tag too - but the `alt` tag can (should?) contain a description. Length doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SEO, it is simplest if all text you want the search engine to see is in your actual HTML markup.  Rather than change the innerHTML on one div, you might put multiple divs next to each other and just hide/show the right ones.  Then all text will be in the markup.

Thumbnail descriptions also belong in the `alt` attribute on the image and search engines look for them there.  I don't know exactly how your app works to know if that's sufficient, but you may at least want to also put the descriptive text there.

Comment: I thought that if I write `style="visibility:hidden"` or `display:none` then the robots will also ignore it (because of spammers..), was I wrong?

Comment: If you want the maximum chance of a search engine seeing your text, make it visible in the markup of the page and also put it in the `alt` attribute for the image and don't hide anything - end of story.  I thought you didn't want to do that so you were asking for the next best thing.  The next best thing I know about is to have it in your markup and toggle the visibility with javascript according to which piece of text you want shown when.  Inserting the text via javascript is much less likely to be seen by a search engine.